# I have to get/I got to get

Tags: difference

Could someone please explain to me the difference between "I have to get" and "I got to get"?

I have to get some sleep now, so let's talk tomorrow, okay?

I got to get some sleep now, so let's talk tomorrow, okay?

Comment: It would be more appropriate to compare *I have to get* with *I **have got** to get*. The existing comparison is simply the difference between the present and the past—and the past-tense version, if it is such, would be *I got to get some sleep yesterday*.

Comment: Some slang or casual dialects say "I got to (or 'gotta') _do something_" when they mean they have to do something. Especially in the US.

Comment: As @MichaelHarvey says, "I got to get" is a substandard variant of "I've got to get".

Comment: But also note the literal meaning of "to get to do sth", which is "to have an opportunity to do something" - in general a sentence like "I got to drive home" is ambiguous between "I had a chance to drive home" and "I have to drive home". In OP's example, the slang meaning @MichaelHarvey notes is probably intended, as the sentence talks about the present/near future.

Comment: Who says it is the 'literal' meaning? Sounds pretty dialect to me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-to - I can't really tell if it's a dialect usage from that, but in my experience it's pretty widespread. COCA list a lot of examples for eg. "get to see"

Comment: I meant "mainly US English". It is an Americanism.

Answer (score 1):

"Have to" means "must", indicating obligation. So, this sentence:

> I have to get some sleep now

is equivalent to:

> I must get some sleep now

Next, "got to":

Explanation 1:

"I got to" is an abbreviation of "I've got to".
"Got is a filler word ... with no obvious grammatical or semantic function."  ([wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/got#English))
If the filler (and thus useless) word is removed, the translation becomes: "I got to" -> "I've got to" -> "I have to".

Explanation 2:

Alternatively, you may interpret "got" directly as meaning "must" or "have to".  So, "I got to" -> "I have to".

Both of the explanations lead to the same result of "I have to".

> Does that mean "I have to" and "I got to" are the same then?

They both mean "must", indicating obligation. However, "got" is informal/colloquial. The plain "got" without "have", even more so - the dictionary mentions "nonstandard".

Comment: “I got to” can also be the past of “I get to”.